# How to block firestore REST API access

Tags: firebase, rest, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a flutter app and use *firebase auth* and *firestore*. The data in *firestore* is only read and written from within the app.

I just realized, that every authorized user can access his data in firestore via the REST apis, if he has a correct auth token (e.g. from the AUTH rest api) and the API_KEY. As I understand, the API_KEY [is not private](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys#api-keys-for-firebase-are-different).

So, even if I set up my security rules correctly, so that a user can only read and write his data, he could still access and change the data via the REST API. This could break my data model, as the data has to be structured in a special way.

Is there any way to allow access to firestore only from within the app and block it from REST calls?

Why are firebase API keys default unrestricted?

Should I limit the key to be used only by the Android APP like described [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be validating the data requests within Security Rules to ensure that your data structure is being adhered to in all cases.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/data-validation

as for the Rest API, it is not possible to outwardly block or deny it as it is built into GCP's core as part of the public API, however, you may be interested in App Check which can deny requests from outside your Android/iOS/Web app
https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check

it's in early Beta and can help with unsolicited abuse to the mentioned platforms.

Comment: Ok, that sounds interesting, but what about Firestore?

It seems it is not yet supported.
  
App Check currently works with the following Firebase products: Realtime Database, Cloud Storage, Cloud Functions (callable functions)

Comment: this is true, but it is in development and will most likely resolve this issue in the near future. ultimately, the real focus should be on Security Rules and strict validation. so even if users have access via rest API, their actions are valid within your ecosystem

Comment: But is there any way to ditsinguish between App access and REST Api acces? I would like to have my app to read/write to the Database with the ID of the user, but the REST access should not see the whole datastructure nor even edit it. I would like to give the users only access via an own API implemented via cloud functions.

Comment: there is none as the rest API has the same methods that the app modules have, including edits and authentication. if you desire this, I highly suggest making a feature request to Firebase

Comment: It is still a bit difficult to understand to me. e.g. Firebase Auth can't be tailored to allow only signIn and no signUp. The API_KEY has not to be private as described in the docs, but we have Email/Password in Auth active and with the API_KEY everybody could e.g. create new users. I thought about letting our API useres authenticate directly against firebase auth and the use the idToken to use our API. Now we are thinking about having our own /login endpoint, which forwards the requests to Firebase Auth. This way we don't have to share the API key.

Comment: I think the longterm solution is to enable AppCheck (for Auth, Firestore when available)  to limit access only to authorized Apps and do the rest via cloudFunctions and the admin SDK.

Comment: I just realized, that it is not possible to keep the API_KEY private. If a user can reset his password, the reset link contains the API_KEY.

Comment: that is correct, but that is because the API_KEY is not a secret. it's publicly accessible and required.

Comment: We are now using appcheck and it is working fine.